# How to pass down Context(React) as a prop, from a higher order Component to the wrapped Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, formik, react-context

For a simple user-registration form that has a few input fields, check-boxes and a submit Button,
I have decided to go with [Formik](https://formik.org/) for obvious reasons such as Form-Validation, Error-Messages etc..,

With the help of [withFomrik()](https://formik.org/docs/api/withFormik), i have wrapped my Form that has all these input fields, check-boxes, submit-button etc..,

Now, I have the following Problem.

I want to pass down the Context(ReactContext) from this higher order Component that is returned by withFormik(), down to the wrapped Component, which is my Form, that needs access to the Context.

P.S: I am trying to control displaying a loadingAnimation that has to be displayed when the Form is being submitted and as soon as any kind of response is returned from the End-Point, the flag is to be set to false immediately. For the implementation, I thought it was a good idea to create Context, so that the flag is available globally.

Any other Ideas of approching this Problem for example using Hooks are more than welcome.

Here is what my code looks like now.

```
function Form(props) {
  const { values, touched, errors, isSubmitting, handleChange, handleSubmit } =
    props;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {isOverlayDisplayed ? (
        <Backdrop
          sx={{ color: "#fff", zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1 }}
          open={true}
        >
          <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
        </Backdrop>
      ) : (
        <Box>
          <Logo />

          <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Info />
            <span className="teilbereichHrLine"></span>

            <InputField
              required
              name="vorname"
              autoComplete="given-name"
              label={"Vorname"}
              error={touched.vorname && Boolean(errors.vorname)}
              helperText={touched.vorname ? errors.vorname : ""}
              value={values.vorname}
              handleChange={handleChange}
            />

            <InputField
              required
              name="nachname"
              autoComplete="family-name"
              label={"Nachname"}
              error={touched.nachname && Boolean(errors.nachname)}
              helperText={touched.nachname ? errors.nachname : ""}
              value={values.nachname}
              handleChange={handleChange}
            />

            <Button
              type="submit"
              variant="outlined"
              size="medium"
              disabled={isSubmitting}
              onClick={handleSubmit}
            >
              ABSENDEN
            </Button>
          </form>
          <Footer />
        </Box>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const AnmeldeFormular = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: ({
    vorname,
    nachname,
    /*
    and a bunch of few other Props
    */
  }) => {
    return {
      vorname: vorname || "",
      nachname: nachname || "",
    };
  },
  validationSchema: yup.object().shape(validationSchema),
  handleSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSubmitting(false);
      sendFormData(values);
    }, 1000);
  },
})(Form);
```